# how to pass the new text value in a form to jsp dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

i have the following code:

```
code here: <input type='text' id='2' value='10:00' />
```

This is an editable text box field with pre-populated data. How do I get the new value of the textbox in jsp whenever user enters a new value. please help.

Comment: in the same jsp page.

Comment: basically the new text value should replace the 10:00 and display that. thus, how can we get the text value in the box and assign to a jsp variable. i need to do this because i need to make use of the jsp variable for data manipulation etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this .

```
<input type='text' id='2' value='10:00' onkeyup="get(this)"/>
```

use this script in head tag

```
<script>
function get(text)
{
var input = text.value;
alert(input);   //displaying the  value

}


</script>
```

Comment: all i did was assigned it to javascript variable: var val = document.getElementById('2').value;

Comment: @TarlochanGill the above code does it ok, simply if you do val = document.getElementById('2').value; it will work only on page load. but above code works whenever a value is entered into the input box

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have the following jsp (add name to your input), assume that you submit this form to the same jsp (which is `someAction.jsp`, though it should be servlet or controller).

```
<form action="someAction.jsp">
<input type='text' name='myName' id='2' value='10:00' />
<input type='submit' value="Submit">
</form>
```

Then you click submit button and you can get this variable myName in the jsp/servlet/controller:

```
    // this will be value of this textbox
    // what user entered (as I understand you would like to know that).
    String someVar = request.getParameter("myName");
```

Comment: all i did was assigned it to javascript variable: var val = document.getElementById('2').value;

Comment: You asked how to assign it to jsp variable (which is server-side variable).

Comment: yeah, from java script i can assign it to jsp variable easily.